# How to sync two tables with two different mysql database in real time?

Tags: php, mysql, synchronization

I need a two way synchronization of tables if some thing insert in
database1 's table then that thing automatically insert into another
database which is database2's table. Could be possible in PHP? Is
there any step by step procedure which can i follow for two different
database which is stored on two different servers.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql

Comment: @chris85: There are two different database i want if one table data is update in first database that data is updated in second database with another table and vice versa

Comment: Oh so both are being written to, yea standard replication wouldn't work there.

Comment: Is trigger or events help ?

Answer (score 1):

it is "possible" (in general), but not immediate. for immediate action *within the transaction* you would need to do it on the DBMS with [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) and [procedures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html). so have a look there.

doing it in PHP it may probably mess up things, but you can check on "db1" for a change since last check and process it to "db2". but if there is one transaction on "db1" and the next on "db1" follows fast, the data might not be in the state you wish to have.

or you just build the architecture differently as this sounds a bit odd to me. your description doesn't really tell why this would be done that way or even why there is need for two databases.